Can't build the MAUI Project for Android, IOS and Mac Os on Windows
I try to build the MAUI project. However, I encounter the following errors.
Error NETSDK1178 : The project depends on the following workload packs that do not exist in any of the workloads available in this installation: Microsoft.Android.Sdk.net8
You may need to build the project on another operating system or architecture, or update the .NET SDK.
Error NETSDK1178 : The project depends on the following workload packs that do not exist in any of the workloads available in this installation: Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk.net8.0_18.0
You may need to build the project on another operating system or architecture, or update the .NET SDK.
Error NETSDK1178 : The project depends on the following workload packs that do not exist in any of the workloads available in this installation: Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0 Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk.Aliased.net8.0_18.0
You may need to build the project on another operating system or architecture, or update the .NET SDK.
Error NU1012 : Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net8.0-android, net8.0-ios, net8.0-maccatalyst
0>------- Finished building project: Gift.PresenterApp. Succeeded: False. Errors: 4. Warnings: 0

I have the following specifications:
OS: Windows 11
IDE: Rider 2024.2.5
.Net SDK version: 8.0.402
Processor: 12th Intel Core I7-12650H
Feel free to contact me if you need to clarify anything else.
I have tried to install appropriate workloads, but not all have been installed. Here are the installed workloads.
Workload ID       Description                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------
aspire            .NET Aspire SDK                                   
macos             .NET SDK Workload for building macOS applications.
maui-tizen        .NET MAUI SDK for Tizen                           
maui-windows      .NET MAUI SDK for Windows

Here is the output from the executed commands. Outputs are the same for the following command.
Executed commands
dotnet workload install maui
dotnet workload install android
dotnet workload install ios
dotnet workload install maccatalyst

Output:
Workload installation failed: Workload ID maui isn't supported on this platform.

Did you try to restart the Visual Studio after install the sdk? Or did you try to install the maui component by the Visual Studio Installer?

What's your CPU?

That last error message seems very descriptive... What is the machine that you are trying to do this on? It seems a machine that is not supported to developer .NET MAUI on at this time.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT , I don't use VS. Instead, I use Rider and Powershell

@Martheen , 12th Intel Core I7-12650H

@GeraldVersluis , Here are the specs of my PC:
OS: Windows 11 IDE: Rider 2024.2.5 .Net SDK version: 8.0.402 Processor: 12th Intel Core I7-12650H
